# Allow to select only each 30 days from selected date in jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have to date inputs on my page: from - to.

I would need to set selectable dates in "to" input dynamically the way that, if user selects in "from" input date `01/01/2021` (DD/MM/YYYY), than in "to" input will be possible select only `01/02/2021`, `01/03/2021` and so on. If user selects in "from" input date `15/11/2021`, than in "to" input will be possible select only `15/12/2021`, `15/01/2022` and so on.

The idea of this is that our service can be ordered only to full month, but from any date client wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with below code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>datepicker demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#txtFrom").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        minDate:"0d",
        onSelect: function (selected) {
            var dt = new Date(selected);
            dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
            $("#txtTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
        }
    });
    $("#txtTo").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: isAvailable,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function (selected) {
            var dt = new Date(selected);
            dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
            $("#txtFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
        }
    });
    
    function isAvailable(date) {
      var fromDate = $("#txtFrom").val();
      var fromDt = new Date(fromDate).getDate();
      var dt = new Date(date).getDate();
      if (dt == fromDt) {
        return [true,"",""];
      } else {
        return [false,"",""];
      }
    }
    
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td>
        From:
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="txtFrom" />
    </td>
    <td>
        &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
        To:
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="txtTo" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect, it does exactly what I need. Thank you very much.